# I am using intro js angular 8 and select option is not working

Tags: angular, intro.js

When I click on the select option it the options are behind the introjs.

 How to bring it to the top?[image: into.js select option not working]

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr *ngIf="emptyList">
        <button (click)='gotoCreatePage()'>Create page</button>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="emptyList==false">
        <td>
            <div id="editPageStep1" #editPageStep1 style="width: 250px;height: 60px;">
                <mat-form-field style="float: left;">
                    <mat-label>Select form page to edit</mat-label>
                    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="pageSelectedData" (selectionChange)="selectPageForEditing($event)">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of pages;let ffsi=index" [value]="ffsi">
                            {{item.title}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <div id="editPageStep2" #editPageStep2 *ngIf="enableEditButton" style="float: left;padding: 10px;">
                <img (click)="tellChildchangingAuthValue(true)" *ngIf='!authRequired' width="25px" height="25px" src="assets/millastudio/page/icons/lock_unselected_50.png">
                <img (click)="tellChildchangingAuthValue(true)" *ngIf='authRequired' width="25px" height="25px" src="assets/millastudio/page/icons/lock_selected_50.png">
                <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="tellChildUpdate()">Update</button>
            </div>
        </td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td *ngIf="checked&&isPageSelected">

            <create-page [callingUpdate]='callingUpdate' [changingAuthValue]='changingAuthValue' [emptyList]="isEmptyList()" [mHomePage]='newPage' [editMode]="true"></create-page>
        </td>
        <td *ngIf="!(checked&&isPageSelected)">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show your implementation.

Comment: Updated in question, please check   editPageStep1

Comment: not clear your problem, do u have some code please ?

Comment: Code is added above

Comment: Problem is when i click on select the option is not visible when intro js is highlighted that div

Comment: When i click on that select the option is showing but not visible to top of the into js showin div

Comment: try to modify z-index by css

Comment: How to do that ? I am a native android developer